# An Old 80's or early 90's Movie involving a Magic Coin

Tags: story-identification, movie, magic

I am looking for any information about an old 80's - early 90's movie involving 2 guys who find a magic coin and make wishes from it. The only parts I can recall is I think one of the guys wishes for a Girlfriend and a woman in Gypsy like clothing comes to him and they both make out at what I think was a mini-golf course and I think at the end of the movie right before the credits he sees her on a beach but I could be wrong. The second part I can remember is that they are magically transported onto a train where the bad guy in the movie is on another train and they are both about to collide when one of the guys flips the coin over and I think it was a smiley face on the coin and they are transported out before the trains collide killing the bad guy but not them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some elements are misremembered, however I can say with absolute certainty this is [*Saturday the 14th Strikes Back*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096039/?ref_=fn_al_tt_3).

*You have to play miniature golf Eddie*

*Listen to your teacher, come on and be a creature*

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. I've been looking for that for years and I have even recently saw the first one which is funny because I have the first one on DvD and never knew there was a second or that it was the one I needed. Yeah It does look like I mixed up a few parts and I thank you.

Comment: @Des If this has answered your question please remember to [accept](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it.

Comment: Sorry thought I had accepted it. THank you for reminding me.